# How to use scala for a backend?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, backend, web-development-server

I'm writing a uber-like mobile app for an academic project. This app is only a front-end for a system running on a server. This system, the backend is responsible for the user database, a search engine, messaging system and a location service (tracking system as in uber). I'm totally new to server development. My problems are:

- How scala can be used to implement a backend?
- How to handle concurrency, user authorizations, messaging and GPS data?

Additionally, In what cases should I use Kafka and Spark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to go with play-framework. It has some learning curve, but once you start learning it seems quite interesting and is quite powerful too.

You must be familiar with scala, concurrency terms like future, actor and some database knowledge would be enough to start.

You can start by doing the examples provided in the documentation.

https://www.playframework.com/

All the best with your learning:)